# Multiple live stream video publishers using FMS, Wowza, etc.?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, flash-media-server

I need to develop a web portal with multiple live stream publishers (up to 4), and many viewers, using RTMP.

Live video publishers are well known and always the same, so in the case of using FMS (since I have some experience with Flash and Influxis), I would have no problem of using FMLE for video publishers. But the problem is how to synchronize in the media server all 4 connections to show properly on the client side. I have tested the one-connection live example that brings FMS and works fine.

Video resolution is not an issue, since we don't mind low resolution 320x240 for example. Also, we need to develop the plaform by ourselves, not depending on external platforms of live streaming. Is there any tutorial or example to use as a start point?

What would you suggest?? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have now found the solution and, I have to say, was extremely easy. I write if someone else has the same problem.

Finally I've solved with Flash Media Live Encoder. You have to create 4 (in my case) video objects in your webpage like below, changing localhost for your hostname.

```
<object width='640' height='377' id='StrobeMediaPlayback' name='StrobeMediaPlayback' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000'>
    <param name='movie' value='swfs/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf' />
    <param name='quality' value='high' />
    <param name='bgcolor' value='#000000' />
    <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true' />
    <param name='flashvars' value='&src=rtmp://localhost/live/livestream&autoHideControlBar=true&streamType=live&autoPlay=true' />
    <embed src='swfs/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf' width='640' height='377' id='StrobeMediaPlayback' quality='high' bgcolor='#000000' name='StrobeMediaPlayback' allowfullscreen='true' pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' flashvars='&src=rtmp://localhost/live/livestream&autoHideControlBar=true&streamType=live&autoPlay=true' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'> </embed>
</object>
```

As you can see, by default the stream name is "livestream", you have to change for every object to be different. Ensure "live" folder is created (when you install FMS in localhost by default creates this folder, but in influxis you have to create manually).
Every video publisher has to open Flash Media Live Encoder and change the Output value of "Stream" by the value of stream name of the respective video object.

That's it! Works perfectly, great resolution and great performance, better than expected. Hope it helps!